# NancyFx not reaching pipelines.OnError

Tags: c#, nancy

I am checking Authentication within a route like this:

```
private dynamic GetAll()
{
    this.RequiresAuthentication();
    var data = _tourRepository.GetAll();
    return Response.AsJson(data);
}
```

If the user is not authenticated, `RequiresAuthentication()` is throwing an error which is **not** leading me into the pipeline's OnError:

```
protected override void ApplicationStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, IPipelines pipelines)
{
    StaticConfiguration.DisableErrorTraces = false;
    pipelines.OnError += (ctx, ex) =>
    {
        if (ex is RouteExecutionEarlyExitException)
            return ((RouteExecutionEarlyExitException)ex).Response;

        return new Response { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError };
    };
    base.ApplicationStartup(container, pipelines);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Call the base then add the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks Phill but it's still not working.